# Getting system mouse coordinates from an air application running on system tray ( mouse tracker )

Tags: air, adobe, system-tray, mouse-coordinates

I want to get the mouse position from an adobe air application that will run on system tray (`visible = false`). I tried lots of ways but couldn't find an answer. 
Is it allowed to get this data with air sdk ? If it is, how?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, you can use https://github.com/pcichon/DesktopMouse

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [NativeMouse](https://github.com/rozd/native-mouse) - this native extension is based on DesktopMouse and works for both Mac and Windows.